# How to use media queries for change positions

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My website works properly for normal screens, but I have some problems in mobile version

Here's my code:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #F4f4f4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background: #131313;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}


/***************************************************************** ANIMAZIONI ***********************************************************************************************************************/


/* Img */

img {
  
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Welcome */

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #131313;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: ;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: top 1s 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: translateY(-130px);
  border: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
}

   
/* Container & Img */

#container {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px 0px aliceblue;
}

#container .intro {
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

img[src*="fras"] {
  margin-top: 1%;
}

img[src*="aka"] {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

div#ddfumetto {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 8s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 8s;
  -o-animation: fadein 8s;
  animation: fadein 8s;
  background: #131313;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
  height: 400px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-right: 1.6%;
}

#desc {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 145%;
  height: 400px width: 40%;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 8s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 8s;
  -o-animation: fadein 8s;
  animation: fadein 8s;
  background: #131313;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-right: 1.6%;
  padding: 2%;
}

#desc a,
#ddfumetto a,
{
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#desc a:hover,
#ddfumetto a:hover,
{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Start  */

.start {
  background: #191919;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 77%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}


/****************************************************** MOBILE *****************************************/


/****************************************  300 t 600 *************/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  div#ddfumetto {
    /* 1st text */
    border: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #desc {
    /* 2nd text */
    border: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .intro {
    text-align: justify;
    border: 0px;
  }
  .start {
    border: 0px;
    background: #131313;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .start>p {
    margin-top: 530%
  }
  .logo img {
    max-width: 230px;
    / object-fit: contain;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px
  }
  p.intro {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  #container {
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #131313;
  }
}


/********************* 601 to 1000 *******************/

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 601px) {
  div#ddfumetto {
    /* First text */
    border: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #desc {
    /* 2nd text*/
    border: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .intro {
    text-align: justify;
    border: 0px;
  }
  .start {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    */
  }
  .start>p {
    margin-top: 140%
  }
  .logo img {
    max-width: 230px;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px
  }
  p.intro {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  #container {
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #131313;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <title>
    Yeah
  </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>



  <div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p class="intro">intro one <i>bla bla bla</i> bla bla <i>"blabla"</i> </p>
    <p class="intro">scope </p>
    <p class="intro">intro site</p>
    <p class="intro">bla bla bla bla<abbr title="DD">blabla</abbr> bla bla bla bla</p>

    <!-- Img1 -->
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/frasissime.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/immagini-con-frasi-sul-karma.jpg?fit=1024%2C576&ssl=1">
    </div>
    <!--- Img2  -->
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://staticfanpage.akamaized.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2020/02/buon-san-valentino-immagini-2.jpeg">
    </div>

    <!-- Text 1st -->
    <div id="ddfumetto">
      <p>bla bla bla bla
        <b>bla</b> bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Text 2 -->
    <div id="desc">
      <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Start page -->
  <div class="start">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

On mobile I would that #ddfumetto and #desc with media queries are readable, basically

- The images
- text 1
- text 2
- then the main

But the text 1 and text 2 in mobile simulation are overlapping or work weird, and I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Please describe the problem with more accuracy, describe what you are trying to achieve and remove all irrelevant code.

Comment: it's simple..in mobile version the text 1 (#ddfumetto) and the text 2(#desc) are overlapping or work weirrdly and I would were readable as after the images we can read text 1 then text 2 then the main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have several problems in code . Firstly your media query order is wrong. And I updated also some parts in media query css codes.

I changed your paragraph css like

```
display:contents;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
```

and in div i changed your element places which image come first text come seconds.

```
<div class="logo"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/frasissime.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/immagini-con-frasi-sul-karma.jpg?fit=1024%2C576&ssl=1">
    </div>
     <div id="ddfumetto">
      <p>bla bla bla bla
        <b>bla</b> bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
    </div>
    <!--- Img2  -->
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://staticfanpage.akamaized.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2020/02/buon-san-valentino-immagini-2.jpeg">
    </div>

    <div id="desc">
      <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
```

U can check it here

https://jsfiddle.net/rm82fkL1/